# Suppose $x:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is continuous and $x(0)=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $x:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is continuous and $x(0)=0 $
If $$(x(t))^2 \leq  2+\int_{0}^{t}x\left(s\right){\rm d}s .
$$  for all $t \geq 0$,
Then which of the following is true?

$a$) $x(\sqrt2)\in[0,2]$

$b$) $x(\sqrt2)\in [0,\frac3{\sqrt2}]$

$c$) $x(\sqrt2) \in [\frac5{\sqrt2},\frac7{\sqrt2}]$

$d$) $x(\sqrt2)\in [10,\infty)$

I tried function $x=0$ and $x=\frac{3t}2$.
And I want to discard $a$ or $b$ ...(as I think $a$ should be wrong and $b$ is answer) not arguments like $a$ is true then $b$ should be true and only one answer can be correct so $b$ is correct.

Comment: Please, use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, for a better formatting of your question

Comment: Just tell me please what to use for greater then or equal

Comment: Do you mean $X(t)=x(t)$?

Comment: For future references \geq or \ge for greater or equal to

Comment: Great I was about to wrote that but have to learn a lot in writing ques in this

Comment: For $x(t)=\frac{3t}{2}$ you get $\frac{9 t^2}{4}\leq \frac{3 t^2}{4}+2$ which is false. I think that $x(t)=\frac{t}{2}$ is the solution, which leads to answer (a) because $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\approx 0.7$. I got $\frac{t}{2}$ differentiating the relation $2x(t)x'(t)\leq x(t) $ which is $x'(t)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and integrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the correct inequality is $x(t)^2\le2+\int_{0}^{t}x(s)\,ds$.
In that case, let $y(t)=2+\int_{0}^{t}x(s)\,ds$. We have $x(t)=y'(t)\le\sqrt{y(t)}$, so
$$\frac{y'(t)}{2\sqrt{y(t)}}\le\frac12$$ and thus
$$x(t)\le\sqrt{y(t)}=\sqrt{y(0)}+\int^t_0\frac{y'(t)}{2\sqrt{y(t)}}\,dt\le\sqrt{y(0)}+\frac{t}2=\sqrt{2}+\frac{t}2.$$ So $x(\sqrt{2})\le\frac32\sqrt{2}=\frac3{\sqrt{2}},$ meaning it's b).